# jQuery select if no predecessor matches class

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint

In my Sharepoint portal I am trying to fix a problem where the lists are wider than the page borders (custom master page) and look funny when they display on the far right.  So I am writing a jQuery function that will reset the width.

My function works fine, so fine that it works in Sharepoint dialogues, too - but I don't want it to work in dialogues!

Here is my method of selecting the elements, which works.

```
var elements = $(".s4-wpcell-plain > div > *, #pagebody.s4-ca > div > *");
```

However, I want to exclude matching if the page is run in a dialogue.  Now, there is a `.ms-dlgContent` style, but it is way above (like, parent of parent of parent, etc...) any of the elements I'm using in my selector match.

How can I match my element if there is no predecessor that matches that class?

**[update]**

Well, thank you, faithful jQuery gurus for such quick responses.  But I tried all of your techniques and it doesn't quite do the trick, so let me explain a bit more (sorry I didn't think of this before).

Here is the css path to the `#pagebody` div in the dialogue.  You can see the class specifying the dialog at the start.

> html.ms-dialog body form#aspnetForm div#s4-workspace.s4-nosetwidth
>   div#s4-bodyContainer div#ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv div#pagebody.s4-ca

This is the css path of the `#pagebody` element for the regular page.

> html body form#aspnetForm div#s4-workspace.s4-nosetwidth
>   div#s4-bodyContainer div#ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv div#pagebody.s4-ca

So, I need to affect the `#pagebody` for just the main page and not the dialogue.  Keep in mind that I want to avoid selecting anything based on the Sharepoint-generated GUIDs.

**[edit]**

Uh, sorry, after looking at those paths, now I realize I have to use `ms-dialog` instead ot `ms-dlgContent`.  I'll mark the answer now.

Comment: This question should be tagged as `CSS` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elements = $(".s4-wpcell-plain > div > *, #pagebody.s4-ca > div > *");

var elementsNotInDialoge = elements.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).parents('.ms-dlgContent').length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var elements = $(".s4-wpcell-plain > div > *, #pagebody.s4-ca > div > *")
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).closest('.ms-dlgContent').length == 0;       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I assume that your `.ms-dlgContent`is a div):

```
var elements = $("div:not(.ms-dlgContent) .s4-wpcell-plain > div > *, #pagebody.s4-ca > div > *");
```